# macOS Safari 16.1 - can't save after customizing toolbar

Tags: macos, safari, bug, ventura

When I right click on the toolbar in Safari and then select `Customize toolbar...` from the context menu, the toolbar gets permanently stuck in "*edit mode*". I tried everything to get out of it, but only thing that works is quitting Safari altogether.

Anyone else has this issue? Anyone knows how to fix it, or why is it happening?

See video for demonstration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghPPE.jpg